# Which "file system type" to choose in "parted" for an LVM volume?

Tags: filesystems, rhel, lvm, parted

Running RHEL 8, the parted utility asks for a "File system type" for the partition being created.
If I plan to use LVM which should I choose? does it matter or I can choose any type of file system (swap,ext4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filesystem type is optional, you can just use `mkpart <part type> <start> <end>`, for example `mkpart primary 1 100` to skip the filesystem type question. You can than toggle the `lvm` flag on the partition with `set <part num> lvm on` to give the "correct" partition id if you want, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. But can specifying the FS type create problems? Let's say I chose "swap" in parted and then use it as a logical volume with an XFS filesystem

Comment: The "swap" choice will affect only the PV partition, not the logical volume created later, so the only problem is that you'll have a LVM PV with a swap partition ID and it doesn't really matter -- the partition ID/types are mostly ignored by the system tools and are important only for partitions that "participate" in the early boot process -- /boot/efi partition must have the correct type for your system to boot, but for other partitions the type is mostly optional and not used.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: How do you toggle the `lvm` flag on the partition?

Comment: `set <part num> lvm on` (I also added it to the answer)